# Prove existence of different programs printing each other code

Tags: computability-theory

How to prove that there exist two different programs A and B such that A printing code of B and B printing code of A without giving actual examples of such programs?

Update: We could prove via Kleene's recursion theorem that there is program printing it's own code. I tried to apply similar technics but didn't succeed.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question does not appear to be a question directly related to mathemtical research (otherwise please provide that link via an [edit]). You might ask such a question on [CS.SE] or [math.SE] But please check their respecitive FAQs and possibly add some more details to your question.

Comment: Interesting question! I think it is fine for MO. The answer is likely a species of the Kleene recursion theorem...

Comment: What do you mean by not giving an example?  The usual way to do this a recursion theorem argument; does giving a program in pseudocode which includes the "Get my own code" operation count as an example?

Comment: I agree with JDH that this is not off-topic, but I think the question should be made more precise.  Are we talking about a specific programming language?  A class of programming languages?  Why the prohibition on exhibiting examples?

Comment: Henry, I think that 'Get my own code' is valid operation here. Timothy, any programming language that gives us Godel numbering should have such programs.

Comment: This is a neat problem, but I've seen this as a homework assignment in introductory computability theory courses, so I'm not sure this is appropriate for MO. (Still, I haven't voted to close.)

Comment: Thanks for the update; I canceled my initial vote to close. (I am still not completely convinced; but it is also not my field of expertise, so others should raher decide.)

Comment: Answered on CS http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/prove-existence-of-different-programs-printing-each-other-code

Comment: I think that there is a subtle issue or problem with the "get_your_own_code" operation as it is applied in the CS answer. Namely, the recursion theorem really only allows you to get some code that computes the same function, not really exactly your own code necessarily. That is, the recursion theorem says that there is an equivalent program that would get its own code, not that every program can get its own code that way. So that argument over there produces A and B such that A writes a program equivalent to B and B writes a program equivalent to A, rather than actually A and B exactly.

Comment: Meanwhile, my answer here avoids that operation, essentially by adapting the proof of the recursion theorem to this double form.

Comment: See related question http://mathoverflow.net/a/63183/1946 on a similar double fixed-point theorem in first-order logic.

Comment: I suppose that the answer over at CS is correct if one takes the "get_your_own_code" operator at face value, since clearly most modern computers have that capacity, even if this is not usually possible in the other common Turing-complete contexts, such as Turing machines, register machines, etc. In those contexts, one does that kind of thing via the recursion theorem, and in that context, my objection applies.

Comment: Shouldn't the hypothesis to be proved be of the form "for any programming language with property P, programs exist that print each other's code?" And should P be Turing-completeness? If you omit the initial quantifying phrase, then a programming language can be any function that takes a string (source code) as input and gives a string as output. One can then come up with both trivial examples and trivial counterexamples, simply by defining the programming language in a special way. Turing-completeness probably isn't sufficient, either, e.g., you could have a language whose output always [...]

Comment: [...] begins with a character that is never a legal first character for source code.

Comment: Ben, your remark is not correct, because if the output always started with such a character, the model would not be Turing complete. My answer shows that every Turing complete model of computability admits such programs A and B.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: OK, maybe it would be helpful if you could edit the question and put in what you think is the correct statement of the hypothesis. Currently it doesn't quantify over all languages, and it doesn't refer to Turing completeness.

Comment: @BenCrowell I think the question is fine as it is, and just as with every question in computability theory, one should assume that one is using a Turing-complete model of computability (unless stated otherwise explicitly; to use a model that isn't Turing complete would be strange). The question was perfectly clear from the start, and admits a very general positive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any Turing-complete model of computation will have programs with this property. Specifically, let $\varphi_e$ denote the function computed by program $e$, in whatever such system you favor. Define two computable functions $h_1$ and $h_2$ so that

$$\varphi_{h_1(x,y)}(z)=\varphi_x(x,y)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\varphi_{h_2(x,y)}(z)=\varphi_y(x,y).$$

That is, $h_1(x,y)$ is a program that on input $z$ gives the value $\varphi_x(x,y)$ and similarly for $h_2$. We may easily arrange that $h_1(x,y)\neq h_2(x,y)$ for every $x,y$, that is, these programs are different (even if they might sometimes happen to compute the same function), simply by making irrelevant syntactic differences in $h_1(x,y)$ versus $h_2(x,y)$.

Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be the programs for these functions, so that
$\varphi_{d_1}=h_1$ and $\varphi_{d_2}=h_2$. Let
$$A=h_1(d_2,d_1)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad B=h_2(d_2,d_1).$$ These are different because we ensured that $h_1$ and $h_2$ always have different values.  Now simply compute
$$\varphi_A(z)=\varphi_{h_1(d_2,d_1)}(z)=\varphi_{d_2}(d_2,d_1)=h_2(d_2,d_1)=B$$
and
$$\varphi_B(z)=\varphi_{h_2(d_2,d_1)}(z)=\varphi_{d_1}(d_2,d_1)=h_1(d_2,d_1)=A.$$

Thus, regardless of the input, program $A$ will output $B$, and program $B$ will output $A$, as desired.
as desired

Comment: I believe that Raymond Smullyan has various instances of a doubled analogue of the recursion theorem (and tripled, etc.), which is what this argument amounts to. I think Smullyan has a whole book full of these, perhaps someone who knows can post the title.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [quines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)).

It's so boring to use the recursion theorem when one can just enjoy [Dan Piponi's Haskell program that prints out a Perl program that prints out a Python program that prints out a Ruby program that prints out a C program that prints out a Java program that prints out the original program](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2011/01/quine-central.html). And it's just 200 lines of Haskell code, [see this paste](http://lpaste.net/43501/multiquine).

Comment: FWIW My starting point for that was to write a "formal" version of the code based on the description of the Recursion Theorem starting at p.42 of Vicious Circles by Barwise and Moss. Part of the reasoning is here: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/02/third-order-quine-in-three-languages.html

Comment: Yes, that is a nice example! The general method allows one systematically to produce such instances for any programming language at all, simply by picking appropriate functions $h_1$, $h_2$, $h_3$ and so on as in my answer. (Andrej, my solution didn't use the recursion theorem, but rather essentially re-proved this doubled version of it from scratch.)

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain this directly from the recursion theorem as follows: Consider $f(x,y)=x$. By s-m-n, this equals $\varphi_{s(x)}(y)$. We can also demand (by padding) that $s(x)>x$. By the recursion theorem, applied to $g(x,y)=s(x)$, there is an $e$ such that $\varphi_e(y)=s(e)$. The programs $e, s(e)$ print each other.

Comment: Great! This is very nice.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Thanks! I just noticed I didn't make sure in the first version that the two programs are distinct, but I've fixed this now.